# how to change the bind grid view in separately

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

**I created one grid view to get the database table details,**
[image]

**here, when I click the Next Sync button it will pop up this box and I can choose the date and time,**
[image]

**but the problem is when I clicked any Next Sync button only change the first DateTime only,**

**this is the code of the table grid view**

```
<table class="table table-striped border-bottom">
      <thead>
          <tr>
                <th>Select to Sync.</th>
                <th class="sorting">Source</th>
                <th>Last Sync. Date</th>
                <th>Download</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Next Sync Schedule</th>
                <th>Schedule</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: PayrollIntegrationVM.GridDataList">

         <tr>
           <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:SHTYP_IS_MANUAL_SYNC"
                       class="i-checks" name="foo"></td>

           <td data-bind="text:SHTYP_NAME"></td>

           <td data-bind="text: moment(SHTYP_LAST_DATE).format('L LTS')"></td>

           <td>
               <div data-bind="ifnot: SHTYP_SYNC_STATUS">
                   <a href="#" data-bind="click: PayrollIntegrationVM.ErrorLog">
                       <span class="mr-2">
                              <img src="~/Content/img/icon-excel.png"
                                               alt="Download">
                          </span> Download Error Log
                          </a>
                          </div>

           </td>
           <td data-bind="text: SHTYP_SYNC_STATUS? 'Success' : 'Failed'"><a href="#">
                     <i class="fa fa-close text-danger"></i></a></td>
            <td data-bind="text: moment(SHTYP_NEXT_DATE).format('L LTS')" id="SHTYP_NEXT_DATE_GET" 
                 name="Sync_Next_Date"></td>

      <td><a href="#" id="Next-Sync-Value" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sync" 
              name="Next_Sync_button">Next Sync.</a></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
```

**this is the date time picker code**

```
<div class="modal" id="sync" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        
            <div class="modal-body">
                
                    <div class="col ml-5 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="NextSyncDate">
                        <input type="time" class="form-control mt-2" id="NextSyncTime">
                    </div>
            </div>
  </div>

 <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Cancel
      </button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="DoneButtonFunction()">Done</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**this is the script part**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        function DoneButtonFunction() {

        var nextSyncDate = $('#NextSyncDate').val();
        var nextSyncTime = $('#NextSyncTime').val();
        var DateTime = nextSyncDate +" "+ nextSyncTime;
        
        document.getElementById('SHTYP_NEXT_DATE_GET').innerHTML = DateTime; 

        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like in your js function, you find the element with the ID 'SHTYP_NEXT_DATE_GET', and js looks for the first one, try to save the row in the table, or find another way to Identify which 'SHTYP_NEXT_DATE_GET' element you want to edit